# Angular issue on exisiting project

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm on Windows 7.

I imported an Angular project started by a friend, but I had some issue after installing node and angular, I was able to run the project with this command:

```
C:\NG\projectName>npm start
```

But when I try to generate a new component with this command I get an error:

```
C:\NG\projectName\app\components>ng g c myNewComponentName
installing component
Unable to find any apps in `.angular-cli.json`
```

The angular-cli.json file is located here: C:\NG\projectName\node_modules\@angular\cli\blueprints\ng\files\ and contains this code:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "<%= htmlComponentName %>"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "<%= sourceDir %>",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "<%= prefix %>",
      "styles": [
        "styles.<%= styleExt %>"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "<%= sourceDir %>/tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "<%= sourceDir %>/tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "<%= styleExt %>",<% if (!minimal) { %>
    "component": {}<% } else { %>
    "component": {
      "spec": false,
      "inlineStyle": true,
      "inlineTemplate": true
    },
    "directive": {
      "spec": false
    },
    "class": {
      "spec": false
    },
    "guard": {
      "spec": false
    },
    "module": {
      "spec": false
    },
    "pipe": {
      "spec": false
    },
    "service": {
      "spec": false
    } <% } %>
  }
}
```

How can I fix that?

For information:

```
C:\NG\projectName\app\components>ng -v
@angular/cli: 1.2.0
node: 6.11.0
os: win32 x64
@angular/animations: 4.2.5
@angular/common: 4.2.5
@angular/compiler: 4.2.5
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.2.5
@angular/core: 4.2.5
@angular/forms: 4.2.5
@angular/http: 4.2.5
@angular/platform-browser: 4.2.5
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.2.5
@angular/platform-server: error
@angular/router: 4.2.5
@angular/tsc-wrapped: 4.0.3
@angular/upgrade: error
@angular/cli: 1.2.0

C:\NG\projectName\app\components>npm -v
3.10.10
```

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely that the project was not initialized with the angular cli.

Running **`ng init`** in `C:\NG\projectName>` should solve the problem[¹](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/755#issuecomment-219058596)

Comment: Thank you for your help but I have this error:
C:\NG\projectName>ng init
The specified command init is invalid. For available options, see `ng help`.

Comment: Strange. Can you run `dir /a:hd C:\NG\projectName` so that you can see if the `.angular-cli.json` is in the root directory?

Comment: the file is not in the root directory

Comment: OK. So my bad. This [command was deleted recently](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5176). Additionally, [this may be a bug](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6503).

Comment: ok thank you, can I install an older version of angular to fix this issue?

Comment: One possible fix would be to use this [`angular-cli.json`](https://github.com/Nolanus/ng2-page-scroll/blob/master/demo/angular-cli.json) file as a template and copy over your project's name and such into that file once you've placed it into your project's root directory. Don't forget to remove the style's libraries such as normalize and material from this template file's style property.